# Flutter: I wants to show message to the user only if the user reaches end of the ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

Below is my code but it is showing the `SnackBar` frequently when I reach the bottom of `ListView`. It also shows the `SnackBar` on the pages also but I wants to show it only one time how to do that.

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));

 Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final doc = docs[index];
                    print(doc);
                    //_checkController();
                    _scrollController.addListener(() {
                      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
                          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      } else {
                        if (_scrollController.position.pixels !=
                            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                          return null;
                        }
                      }
                    });
                    return builddoc(doc);
                  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning new **listeners** every time **item builder** calls.

put this code in **ititState** so it just called once.

```
                  _scrollController.addListener(() {
                      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
                          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      } else {
                        if (_scrollController.position.pixels !=
                            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                          return null;
                        }
                      }
                    });
```

Comment: Most Welcome :) Please mark the answer as correct. to help others find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the listener from the itembuilder, instead use it in initState(),as everytime item is builded on listview, it will call this listener, so it is going on everytime item get builded.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Listener` on `ScrollController`, your issue is that you assign `Listener` to `controller` in build method which is wrong, you should do it once in `initState`. This is a full example of what you want:

```
class ScrollPageTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollPageTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ScrollPageTest> createState() => _ScrollPageTest();
}

class _ScrollPageTest extends State<ScrollPageTest> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.position.atEdge) {
        if (controller.position.pixels != 0) {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'));
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: Text('data = $index'),
          );
        },
        itemCount: 100,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 bool isSnackBarShown = false;

 ...



    Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemCount: docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final doc = docs[index];
                    print(doc);
                    //_checkController();
                    _scrollController.addListener(() {
                      if ((_scrollController.position.pixels ==
                          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent)
                      && !isSnackBarShown) {
                      isSnackBarShown = true;
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                          } else {
                            if (_scrollController.position.pixels !=
                                _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                              return null;
                            }
                          }
                        });
                        return builddoc(doc);
                      },
```